# Invalid close votes

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, retracted-close-votes

I monitor the [bing-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bing-maps) tag on Stack Overflow. I've noticed from time to time that some people vote to close valid questions. For example, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752712/bing-maps-cluster-pushpin-click) is fairly clear and is very specific, however someone has voted to close it and marked it as too broad. I've answered majority of the questions in this tag and also know the two next most active users in this tag very well and know they wouldn't vote to close this either. Other than us three there are few who answer any questions in this tag which has be thinking that people are voting to close it for one of the following reasons:

- They know nothing about the technology and they don't understand the
  question.
- They are just trying to earn badges.

As for my discussion point, is there a way to manage this? Should a moderator be able to remove a vote like this or highlight it as an invalid vote somehow?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not an expert for the mentioned tags, but the question actually looks _too broad_ for my taste as well. The OP should at least show some attempts and research, when asking about a programming related problem.

Comment: That is clear for you doesn't mean that is clear for anyone that sees the question, or worse, for the one that faces the same problem. Oh, btw, closing questions doesn't earn you badges, at all.

Comment: If someone doesn't know anything about the technology in question they shouldn't be voting on the topic unless it is clearly a poor question.

Comment: That *is* clearly a poor question.

Comment: If you are familiar with the technology the question is pretty specific, thus the answer that was provided to it.

Comment: Um, you don't necessarily have to be familiar with a technology/language to recognize a bad question. Where exactly is your evidence that these close voters know nothing about the tech or don't understand the question?

Comment: We had a very similar question come up a while ago where the 5 close votes on a rather low-level C/C++ question all came from people with <100 rep in C/C++. I think there might actually be some sort of problem along the lines @rbrundritt is stating, but I have no idea how to fix it. I think it's just something to live with and maybe, if egregious, invoke the meta effect on.

Comment: see also: [Should users unfamiliar with a topic wait before voting to close?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358487/839601)

Comment: @tnw, The question is pretty clear, but has a lot of terminology specific to the Bing Maps platform. Anyone who knows the platform would easily understand that question, it is very clearly stated. Looking at all who voted closed on the question, none of them have ever answered a question that had the bing-maps tag. I have also never come across them before, and can saw with confidence they are not experts on Bing Maps. I lead the Microsoft MVP program for Bing Maps and have never seen these users before.

Answer (score 10):

> As for my discussion point, is there a way to manage this?

Yes, ignore it!

This is the system working exactly as intended, a lack of consensus means the close vote *doesn't matter*. This is exactly how the platform is supposed to function.

> Should a moderator be able to remove a vote like this or highlight it as an invalid vote somehow?

No, and we wouldn't want to. There are only 19 of us, there are *tons* of tags where moderators are not qualified enough to *override* somebody else's vote.

Vote how you like. If you disagree that a question should be closed, don't vote to close it. If a question gets closed and you think it shouldn't have, vote to reopen it.

Comment: I do agree with some of your points, however I have found that since the number of people who are knowledgeable about the tag in question is fairly small and I have voted to reopen a number of questions which never get enough votes which is a pain as I have the answer for the question.

Comment: @rbrundritt If you need help getting things reopened that were closed you can always hop into the [SOCVR char room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and ask for help.  We would be more than happy to help you reopen questions that should not be closed.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for the info. I'll keep that in mind the next time I come across an issue like this. Guess I'm just a bit frustrated as I have been leading the development community for this technology for nearly a decade now and I find managing the Microsoft MSDN forums a lot easier. I just hate it when good questions by newer users are down voted or voted to close as it will likely discourage them asking questions again.

Comment: It's not a good question though; it shows zero research effort, which means it _should_ be down voted (see the tooltip on the down vote link). It could potentially be better, the OP mention they have code so that could be added to the question with a description of what's going wrong, for example, but it hasn't been. So at the moment it's still a bad question for the site. It's not good just because it can be answered, our criteria are much stricter than that

Comment: @Clive Then you're welcome to throw your close-vote in. My point has nothing to do with the question, I didn't even read it. I'm answering the meta question about dealing with close-votes you disagree with.

Comment: when a question is voted to close for the wrong reason and isn't the root of the real question, then IMHO it requires a moderator's attention. I recently answered a question that only in comments was the real question revealed, and the OP edited accordingly. I solved the question and asked for the votes to close from a possible duplicate be removed but was declined. I feel that wasn't handled properly and moderators should have removed the 2 votes for what people thought was a possible duplicate. I'd hate to see that question eventually deleted because of someone's "error".