# Should users unfamiliar with a topic wait before voting to close?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Before this is marked as [a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question), hear me out. I've seen this issue a few times for questions tagged [google-home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-home) or [actions-on-google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actions-on-google), with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941546/where-are-google-assistant-applications) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TceP.png)) being the most recent.

Many of these questions get closed "Unclear what you are asking" by people who aren't familiar with the topic. The five people who voted to close in this case don't seem to have any understanding of coding or releasing apps for the Google Home - and, to be fair to them, I can see how they could see the question as unclear.

To those of us who do - the question was perfectly clear (although I edited it to be even clearer, I hope). It could, arguably, not have been in the scope of SO, but I would argue that it is - making the results of coding available for others and discoverable seems relevant, particularly since this is done using one of the developer tools that is essential for developing the app in the first place. The design and development of a voice app is deeply integrated into the discoverability of it, and documentation for voice app development cover all these issues side-by-side.

Is it reasonable to ask moderators to pause a little before passing judgement on topics they're not familiar with? Is it possible to bias people away from moderating topics they're not familiar with? I wouldn't want to *prevent* people from moderating cross-topic, but there are cases where aggressive moderation isn't as helpful.

(Secondarily - I wouldn't mind some other votes to re-open the question. It *is* a reasonable question, and there are some potential answers that are broadly useful to the community.)

Comment: That's not a programming question, so it certainly doesn't belong on the site, whether you think it's clear or not.

Comment: Your argument for this question being in scope is *very* poor. That's like saying that anything that was programmed is on-topic because discoverability of features in that program should be within scope. Just... no.

Comment: @rene I'm now wondering if Prisoner really disliked that question and wanted it to get deleted, so they posted a deliberately inflammatory post advocating it be reopened purely to anger people into deleting it.  If that's the case, I have to say, genius.  I might have to try that some time myself...

Comment: so... the best way to harness the meta effect is to play outraged and expect the community to spring up against you?.... I like it!

Comment: Um... no. I honestly thought the votes to close were overzealous, that the post was on-topic, that answers to the post would help people in the SO community interested in the tagged topics, and that my title was a brief summary of the issue. I was pretty clear in the body that I could understand why the downvoters did it, but felt it should be reopened.

Comment: > 15.5k > doesn't know the question is blatantly off topic > mfw.jpg

Comment: Are people seriously defending voting to close a clear question as unclear just because it's off-topic? Why do we even have specific close reasons then? Let's just revert to the original design of voting to close a question without having to provide a reason - a closed question is a closed question, right?

Comment: @BoltClock *"We are able to dev application for Google Assistant thanks actions. That's great, but where's a "kind of store" for these apps ?"* strikes me as unclear, I could have voted that way myself. It was closed before the edit took it from unclear babbling to simply being offtopic (in my opinion)

Answer (score 22):

Questions like that are:

- Too broad,
- Lacking research and
- Off-topic

They should be downvoted, closed and deleted.

They *certainly* shouldn't be re-opened, even if the applied closure reason isn't the best fit.
For a question that *should* be closed, what matters is that the question is closed.
Don't re-open it if you just want to close it for another reason.

---

Note: You're talking about "Moderators", but none of the users involved in closing / deleting the questions are moderators. They're just users with the required privileges.

Comment: I used the term broadly. I could have said "downvoters", but found that harsh.

And I disagree - the question was not too broad, it asked a specific question in context. It did not lack research - Google's documentation does touch on the issue, but not directly. It was directly on the topic of the tools one uses when developing for the Google Assistant.

I didn't want it re-opened to close it. I wanted it re-opened to *answer* it. As I said in my question here.

Comment: And neither your answer, nor any of the commentary, discuss the issue of people who do not understand the topic of the question being able to close a perfectly reasonable question - even if you disagree that this question passes the "reasonableness" test.

Comment: `They certainly shouldn't be re-opened, even if the applied closure reason isn't the best fit. What matters is that the question is closed.` that's a very exclusionary and anti-community stance. No wonder less experienced developers don't like SO.

Comment: @Prisoner: I'm not a pilot, but I can tell when someone "flying" a plane is doing a bad job. You don't need to be familiar with a subject to recognize it's off-topic.

Comment: @abraham: If a question _should_ be closed, don't re-open it just to change the close-vote. It's a waste of time. I'm _not_ saying _"What matters is that __all__ questions are closed."_

Comment: @abraham How can it be exclusionary and anti-community when the community decided certain questions to be off-topic?

Comment: @Prisoner: "*And neither your answer, nor any of the commentary, discuss the issue of people who do not understand the topic of the question being able to close a perfectly reasonable question*" But your example doesn't show this either, since this is very much ***not a programming question***. Garbage in, garbage out. If you want to have a discussion about that, then present an example that actually exemplifies that.

Comment: @abraham on the other hand, there are plenty of people with a driber’s license that really shouldn’t own a car.

Comment: The question is not about programming. software development in general or the tools used.  Questions about pizza or beer are more on-topic for programmers than that question.

Comment: @abraham I don't need to be a pilot to tell you that a question about how to add an app to an app store isn't an on topic question on an aviation site.  I would feel entirely comfortable closing such a question as off topic, even if I wouldn't have the technical expertise to answer any aviation related questions that would actually be on topic for such a site.

Comment: @abraham: Prove it. Go find *good* questions that were "shutdown" that should not have been. Questions where an expert would not have closed it, but a lay person would have. Because the example here was clearly off-topic.

Comment: @abraham Or they could try to become a contributing member of the community by reading guidelines like the help center and how-to-ask.

Comment: Close reasons are meant to provide guidance to the asker. I don't think that a question should be kept closed with the wrong reason, because then the asker will be given the false impression that the problem with their question is X and not Y. We already have enough of a problem with users not figuring out why their posts were downvoted because the tooltip is so vague and undiscoverable. I don't know of any good ways to remedy incorrect close reasons other than by getting a diamond mod such as myself to do it with binding votes, though.

Comment: @BoltClock: Agreed. My point is more that the whole reopen>close process is a waste of time, without mod intervention.

Answer (score 8):

If I read this in a *different* light, is the question then asking, "How could I get my Google Assistant-driven application into the app store?"  That's the *only* way I could see this having even a remote shot of being on-topic (and even that's iffy - gut tells me that'd still be off-topic).

If I read this at face value, the user is looking for applications for Google Assistant, which is very much ***not*** a programming question or a question in scope here, and it *should* be/remain closed.

Comment: I don't know about you, but the "different" light is exactly how I read it from the get-go, and I had never even *considered* that anyone would read it as "where can I find apps".

Comment: @BoltClock:  That's how I read it the first time, too.  Then the line containing, "...but not apps from all the other developers." dimmed the "different" light.  There are multiple ways to interpret it, which is why it should be closed.  While it's unfortunate that it couldn't be *clarified*, I don't see an issue with the state it's in.

Comment: Hmm, quite unlike @BoltClock, I never even considered that the question might be asking how to get the apps into an app store. In my defense, I got pretty distracted by the giant picture... Still, I'm not convinced that reading makes it on-topic.