# How much background do I need on C library issues for my question on structure compatibility to be clear?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389080/mix-of-c-standard-library-objects-on-macos-or-linux-for-clang-or-gcc) question about standard library structure compatibility between runtimes, which seemed reasonably self-explanatory to me (the issue is well-known on Windows at least, and I assumed someone would be able to tell me whether the same issue exists on other platforms.

But the question was closed as Unclear.

My suspicion is that the folks who closed it were mostly familiar with Java or Python and simply didn't understand the question. Certainly the people who *answered* the question didn't seem confused by it - although they didn't quite cover the aspect of the question I was most interested in, so I was about to set a bounty on it. Now, of course, I can't because the question is closed; I don't even have the option to clarify my question.

So I come here, and ask to all of you: what is unclear about my question?

Comment: *"because they don't seem to understand it"* what gives you that idea?

Comment: In the comments users shared the question is not clear enough. I highly disagree

Comment: None of the close voters commented.

Comment: @HelloWorld How's that actually related to c++ code??

Comment: bsides. Any proof that said users *aren't* proficient at said topic?

Comment: If people posted answers, but they didn't cover the answer you were looking for, could that be an indication that your question is not sufficiently clear? A little humility goes a long way when you're asking volunteers to help you out...

Comment: @KevinB: Yes, they didn't commend what exactly the problem is, that is even less helpful in my opinion.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I highly highly appreciated their answer! But it's not the answers were insufficient or ambigious, more likely said the opposite

Comment: @HelloWorldThey don't have to. That would be an undue barrier to proper and efficient moderation.

Comment: see also: [Should users unfamiliar with a topic wait before voting to close?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358487/839601)

Comment: @HelloWorld  _"So I come here, and ask to all of you: what is unclear about my question?"_ If you come up with a question about a specific programming language you should show concrete attempted in that particular programming language. Otherwise remove the language tag and ask about the broader view please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question seemed clear enough to me, although you kinda mixed in your Windows experience in a way that was overly-noisy - clearly separating your question from tangential / background / research information helps a lot when folks are trying to make sense of it, *regardless* of their own knowledge.

That said, I also think the answers did a reasonable job of addressing it, so I'm not sure what you would've hoped to gain by offering a bounty.

> I don't even have the option to clarify my question.

Here's the kicker: you can easily address *both* of the issues I touched on above *even while the question is closed.* **Just edit it.**

[I made an edit to demonstrate how I would've approached this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48389080/revisions), with the caveat that I *still* don't really know what additional information you're after beyond what has already been provided. Unless the question is *locked*, you can edit it at any time, closed or otherwise, to address complaints, resolve confusion, or add key details on what you're after.

Comment: It indeed seems I missed an edit and the addendum of one of the answers which underpinned my initial suspicion. Back to topic, thanks for your change but even more the change and the way how you would have approached the question in this thread

Answer (score 4):

*Frequently*, comments will tell you what is unclear about your question.  This is thoroughly independent of who closed the question, since you may get people who happen by your question and ask, "wait, what?"

In your case, at least two people felt that it was clear enough to answer, so they did.

You *always* have the option to clarify your question through editing your question.  You just...haven't, which is kind of a shame.

Your question still reads a bit odd to me, and I admit I have no experience in what you're dealing with, but edits would at *least* help your case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your open dialog! Just because someone doesn't understand a question doesn't makes it right to close it. And it doesn't mean the question is not good enough. Yes, two people answered (which proofs people do understand it) but both of them are kind of contradictory so I was about to put a bounty on it, because I still feel the question gives everything you need to answer it properly.

Comment: @HelloWorld: If someone doesn't understand, it's *better* to close it than to let misunderstandings proliferate.  Questions that are unclear have a lot of chatter and noise and are less useful to others than questions which are devoid of that.

Comment: @HelloWorld good thing that you'd be blocked to delete either main or meta question... Deleting questions people put effort to answer is one of the worst and painful behaviors I see on SO... Please don't plan to do it for  the future questions either...

Comment: You're right...