# Should users without relevant tags vote to close "unclear" questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I'm not ranting or anything. This is a genuine question.

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52430106/how-is-stata-implementing-weights) on the main site. It was closed for being "unclear". Now, only 1 out of the 5 users actually have the tag of the question (`Stata`). I presume the other 4 users (all +8k rep) could not understand the question because they have no knowledge of Stata. Is it appropriate/recommended for such users to vote to close? I would suppose it's not.

As the comment to the question suggest, the reason for closing would have been "off-topic". The end result is the same, but the message sent to other users is not.

Update: [The possible duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358487/should-users-unfamiliar-with-a-topic-wait-before-voting-to-close?noredirect=1&lq=1), although asks the same question than me, has no answers that really answer it. Instead, the two answers focus on the particular question of the user that was closed, arguing why it is off-topic. The answer here however does actually answer the fundamental question of the title. So I think it's not really a dupe of that one.

Comment: I would agree here. While I have no idea what this question is about, it *seems* pretty clear and answerable for someone in the field. However, in general, *yes*, anyone should be able to vote as unclear, because a lot of crap clearly is crap even for someone from a different speciality.

Comment: Do note, though, that the fact that I have 0 stata reputation doesn't mean I don't know stata. It just means I don't consider myself experienced enough to actively look for questions to answer with that tag

Comment: The image of relevant documentation is also a bit problematic, though not in itself a red flag. I can see why you did that (formatting math in Markdown without MathJax is a drag or even impossible) but it might have attracted a downvote or two. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @tripleee Yes, without markdown it's too cumbersome. I even thought of posting it in CrossValidated.SE, where there is markdown, but I thought to be more on-topic here than there.

Comment: I understood your question but I voted to close it as primarily opinion based because usually questions of this kind are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Only StataCorp can answer definitively about the inner workings of Stata. The rest is typically speculation. In this particular case, the answerer was observant and noticed that it is a simple issue with scaling the intercept. But I think it is unrealistic to expect people to dive into the inner workings of a proprietary software package in order to find out why your results do not match.

Comment: @Moritz It's just a "statistical" prediction, a generalisation which of course is not always correct.

Comment: @PearlySpencer In principle the ado files are available to the users, although I struggled trying to find the precise way it works in Stata. `regress` seems to call `_regress`, which I could not find.

Comment: @luchonacho The code is often hidden several levels deep and is not available for all commands. In fact, the code for most core commands is compiled in the application itself and thus not visible. In the case of your question, it was an omission from your part which luckily was spotted by the answerer. But if that wasn't the case, it would meant that Stata may be the culprit. The point of my vote and my aforementioned comment is that you cannot realistically expect volunteers on here to dig this stuff up (even if they can). Such questions are better suited for the StataCorp technical support.

Comment: @HansPassant the casting of an “unclear what you are asking” closing vote by _three_ other members here was unfortunate but there is no guarantee that people in the queue would have voted differently. Let’s not condescend a user initiative that attempts to fix one of the most important flaws of Stack Overflow and helps smaller communities to self-moderate.

Comment: Hard to imagine you were happy about that outcome.  Do address that in the chat room instead of addressing me, nothing I can do about it.

Comment: I was not pleased with the outcome and my comment was addressing you for a different reason as stated.

Answer (score 19):

> Should users without relevant tags vote to close “unclear” questions?

Yes. Lots of crap is clearly crap even for someone coming from a different speciality. We want all hands to get rid of that ASAP, so everyone should be able to vote on anything.

Having said that, in this particular case it seems that has gone awry, since your question appears very reasonable and [evidently answerable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52431475/476) for someone versed in the specific technology. Well, looks like [Tim has lost his keys again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/476), but that's no reason to throw the baby out with the bathwater.