# Product owner/moderators for tags

Tags: discussion, support

Note that [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362872/owners-officials-for-a-tag) is similar by title topic, but it is really quite different.

I'm a product owner for a product that has over 150K developers, and have been using Stack Overflow for well over eight years as an additional Q&A forum for technical queries from developers (as Stack Overflow was intended to be used).  We have our own technical forums elsewhere and separate process for general support queries, which doesn't really align with Stack Overflow 's goal, that we manage separately as well. We came to Stack Overflow because we saw developers were already here asking technical questions about our product and wanted to support the community and make sure they got the answers they needed regardless of where they were asking them.

Like many before me, we have encountered a host of headaches when it comes to helping users on Stack Overflow. I don't want to dive into this too much as I don't want to start a heated debate, but a few examples:

- People deleting posts who aren't familiar with the product or don't understand the question (although someone who is using the product would completely understand the question).
- People who don't understand the answer, or the question, and marking the correct answer to be deleted.
- People who do know the product and tried to answer the question by pointing to official resources being hounded/blocked because they added a link to an outside source rather than embedding everything into the post.

Now, my question/request. Can we have tag owners who are the main moderators for a specific tag? I built my reputation up as needed to unlock the moderator tools, but even then I find that I'm occasionally blindsided by someone closing a perfectly acceptable question. I looked at tag sponsorship (we were willing to pay to address this issue), but that only gives us ads, which is nice and all, but it doesn't help address the issue here. Ideally, someone who is a top answerer on a tag and has moderator privilege's would have more control over posts for that tag than a regular moderator who has never posted on that tag before (a super Stack Overflow moderator of course having more privileges than anyone).

Comment: Not hard to figure out the produce you are talking about. The tag wiki for `az..` tag should probably be upgraded significantly to help users know what to ask and where and what not to ask here. I saw one roadmap type question with comment from high rep user voting to close and for good reason based on SO guidelines. Your answer there is basically a link to docs which is fine from a help desk perspective but is a *"link only"* answer that by SO standards on most language tags would be flagged to be closed quickly

Comment: *...they added a link to an outside source rather than embedding everything into the post.* There does need to be enough information in an answer post for it to be helpful even if the link fails: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer . We don't need to be familiar with a product to know that "The thing is [here](http://www.example.com)." isn't an answer according to the site rules.

Comment: I'll have to do some digging, but there was another long discussion on linking to outside official content. There are times when it is valid to do so on SO. Does it really make sense to copy paste a ton of content from the official source into a SO response? It does a lot of damage to SEO for SO and the official site when the same content is repeated.

Comment: All I wanted to do was have a discussion here, but instead I got attacked. Besides this thread I have 6 different people email. 2 where constructive and welcomed, but the other 4 were pure hate mail and a personal attack. I'm trying to help people who found their way to SO and asked a question. All I want to do is help.

Comment: If to write an answer on SO you would need to copy something that is already available elsewhere then why answer it at all? The answer is already available on the internet. If you want to answer here then you must tailor the answer to the particular question. Provide a solution that is not a copy of the manual, but that you have written to satisfy the requirements from the question.

Comment: @rbrundritt The point of SO is to be a repository for knowledge. If you post a link as an answer, you're not adhering to SO's reason for existence. If you care more about SEO for your site than about SO's rules and philosophy, that is perfectly OK, but then don't direct users to SO to ask questions about your product... direct them to your own site instead.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that someone sends you hate mail. If you think it was caused by your interactions on the site, then you should report it to the moderators. This kinds of things are taken seriously.

Comment: I'll see if I can trace back the emailers to their SO username. I don't take it personally that I got hate mail and I could care less about the content of those emails. Just really surprised by it. I've spent 2 hours a day for the last 15 years of my personal time helping developers in online communities. I spend the least amount of time on SO and at times wish I could avoid it all together. But I'm passionate about helping the developer community and those who use my product, where ever they may seek help.

Comment: Long story short, I'm frustrated with some things in SO. I want to help make SO better. I'll still end up using it and helping developers regardless. I started this thread after talking to a developer who had a really bad experience on SO, who just wanted to help, but got blocked before they had a chance to learn all the best practices for SO.

Comment: @rbrundritt SO helps by having the information available. You don't get blocked from reading/searching the questions & answers already available. If you wish to contribute (either by asking or answering) then there's a lot you need to learn. We have high standards on what can be posted here. If someone gets blocked, it means that they haven't done enough reading about our rules and policies and they were the cause for their bad experience themselves.

Comment: Don't underestimate the value of updating the tag wiki either to help prevent users posting questions that get blocked.

Comment: @rbrundritt - don't feel you have to guess at usernames by yourself, there's a [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) linked from the CoC that's a perfectly reasonable way to report abusive users

Comment: You've made a proposal which boils down to "I want to have tags on SO for which I fully control the permitted content, including the standards of quality and topicality". That's *highly* unlikely to happen. You've made claims that questions are closed and questions & answers deleted inappropriately in order to justify your proposal. We *are* concerned about those claims. However, without a direction in which to look and multiple specific examples, it's *impossible* for us to look into such claims, or to even attempt to verify that there is a systemic issue and attempt to address/rectify it.

Comment: Note: that's not to downplay how inappropriate it is for people to have sent you hate emails about this, or about any other issue you might raise. As Flexo said, please use the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) page to let employees know more details.

Comment: Well, the [most likely is acquisition by Microsoft, not an actual IPO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=15m57s), so perhaps it is time to pull some strings? :-)

Comment: Anyway, the questions in that tag are half-way decent (at least superficially). Even then, as there are less than 10 questions per month, it should be possible to make them all *awesome* (near publication quality) by a bit of copy editing, including dressing naked links and correcting the spelling of the (main) product.

Comment: *Does it really make sense to copy paste a ton of content from the official source...* @rbrundritt You actually don't have to copy/paste *anything* from a page you link to. There just needs to be an answer in the answer post itself. You can accomplish that by copy/pasting from documentation but it isn't a requirement. For example, this answer of mine [contains links to W3C documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297746/accessibility-guideline-i-dont-understand/31298263#31298263) but doesn't quote any of it.

Answer (score 36):

What may be perfectly acceptable to you may not be acceptable to the members of the general site, and you may need to bring specific cases into this meta question to allow meta members to see if our views on acceptance align with yours or not. Note that I disagree with your feature request premise as it looks more like a need to control a product support discussion site rather than moderate a specific corner of a general programming Q&A site. If someone's question gets closed, then vote to re-open as your privileges allow, but giving special moderation tools for a tag is not in alignment with what I believe is the purpose of this site. If others disagree, I'm all ears.

Why not instead pay an employee or multiple employees to monitor the relevant tags on this and other sites, and have them promptly and (hopefully) correctly answer the questions that are found. This way, your people get the jump on others who might otherwise harm questions that you feel are important. Having a great answer to a mediocre question *can* reduce its risk of being closed or deleted, but not necessarily since even well-answered questions can get closed and deleted if the question quality is very low or if it considered off-topic. That's how the site works, what makes it different from all other programming-related sites, and why it has succeeded.

Comment: We did try having employees monitor/correct questions, but unfortunately there was again users not familiar with the topic who voted against these users which lead to some of them being blocked on SO. 

In regards to having a great answer to a mediocre question, I've seen these answers deleted in some cases.

Note the product I lead is a developer platform. If companies that owned developer platforms didn't support developers who ask questions about these platforms on SO, half the content on SO wouldn't exist.

Comment: If employees get downvoted that much it could be an indicator that your tag provokes questions or answers that aren't a good fit for a q/a site. What's the main problem? E.g. I would imagine a lot of duplicates if SO is used as a product support site.

Comment: Also, please take a look at these links (not sure they apply in your case, but maybe they help in some way): [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)
and
[Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

Comment: @rbrundritt You keep claiming that people who "vote against" your wishes aren't familiar with your product or do not understand the question/answer. Those words are wind with no concrete examples of where you feel this happened.

Comment: I have looked at those threads and many others. I've come across over a hundred community leaders who are frustrated with parts of SO. This thread is a great example. I wanted to have a healthy discussion, I didn't expect my feature request would be accepted, but overnight I wake up and there are 4 close votes. I wasn't even given a change to address any of the comments, yet people were trying to close it before I could improve it. I see new developers who shy away from SO due to negative experiences. Lets stop the gate keeping. SO is a community, shouldn't the community drive the platform?

Comment: @rbrundritt But that is the whole purpose of closing the question. We close it before you improve it. If you improved it then we would need to review it again and see if it still needs closing or if it was already closed should we reopen it. Closing means that the question is not suitable to receive answers. It works slightly differently on Meta but the idea is the same. People who vote to close are expressing an opinion that the question in its current state would not benefit from answers.

Comment: Just because a lot of people are disagreeing with your proposal doesn't mean that Stack Overflow is bad. It's not a negative experience, **it's just you who perceives it this way**. Unfortunately, not everyone in life will always agree with you. The community drives the content on this platform which is why we review such proposals, vote and express our opinions on Meta.

Comment: @Dharman You might have missed my other comment. I had 4 hate mails in under 12 hours related to this thread from people who found my email online. Most of what they said had nothing to do with SO or me. I'm very receptive of different views, and generally have good experiences on SO. However, there have been a lot of negative experiences I have seen on SO, that wasn't just people disagreeing. This thread was closed before we could discuss it. I didn't expect my request to get approved, but was hoping for a constructive discussion. I come to SO to help developers and share my knowledge.

Comment: The meta site isn't geared towards making large changes in site policy as such decisions would not be made by us but rather by the site owners. They may monitor discussions held here but don't have to get involved or act on issues except in extreme circumstances such as with the Monica debacle. You may wish to try to contact the site owners directly.

Comment: @rbrundritt Accusing others of not understanding something isn't the best way to initiate a constructive discussion, I think if you look through earlier meta posts you'll find that when people bring concrete examples of what they want to discuss to the table, discussion tends to happen. As for the question being closed while you were asleep that is unfortunate but we also can't all adapt to the same timezone.This is a global community, people are online at different times.

Comment: The idea I had in mind and what how I've described it above doesn't align. I'll own that, poor quality question, its marked as close, I'm fine with that. Fixing the question in this thread doesn't make sense as it would not align with the rest of the discussion. I had an idea for a while, but a serious incident that occurred on SO to another person using a tag I rarely use triggered me to submit this idea. This individual has reported the incident through the proper channels.

Comment: Unfortunately I was frustrated with SO and in the middle of working on something else when I posted this, and I didn't clearly describe what I wanted to discuss. I reluctantly added some examples as I was afraid it would spur discussions about individual issues (there is separate thread already for those out there). All communities have issues, I was trying to think of some ideas of how to help improve this.

Comment: I woke up yesterday to some nasty emails related to this thread which put me on the defensive and less accepting of feedback in the comments. I'll own that too. The issue that triggered this thread pretains to a sensitive topic that the SO leadership has aknowledged publicly as a known issue previously. I'm purposely not providing any details on that as that's not my intended focus was for this thread.

Comment: What I originally had in mind was more universal and could be applied to any tag. Basically have weighted moderator rights based on the activity of a tag and the volume of activity the moderator has had with that tag. For example, a moderator who is really active on one tag should have a bit more weight in deciding factors when compared to another moderator who has never interacted with any posts with that tag before. I've learnt from this thread that ideas like this should be submitted to SO directly rather than in Meta, so I'll consider doing that.

Comment: With that, I've spoken my peace. So lets move on.

Comment: I sincerely hope that you can resolve your issues favorably and wish you well

Comment: @rbrundritt I'll just add that it's completely unacceptable for people to harass you over this post. People should be able to have different opinions and thoughts on what's best for the site without resorting to that. I think the discussion here on the site might have taken a more constructive turn with some (anonymised) examples but it is what it is.

Answer (score 15):

I see no reason to do what you are proposing. You would need to provide clear advantages of your solution and explain how the overall developer community would benefit from this change.

#### Regarding the tag in question

I have taken a quick look at the tag [bing-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bing-maps) which I assume you are talking about. I checked some of the questions you have recently answered. They have many quality issues. You seem to treat Stack Overflow as a support desk rather than a Q&A site.

You must remember that we do not answer every question that gets posted here. **[We look for pearls](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/). We try to answer questions we think would have lasting value for the community.** Questions that are clear, useful and likely to be found by people in the future. For this reason we do our best to edit questions as they get posted and when we answer them. Fix all the issues with the question (formatting, grammar, spelling, remove tags from the title, retag properly, and [remove fluff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)). If the question is not suitable then we close it as soon as possible. If the question was already asked and answered on the site then we link it as a duplicate. If all of this fails then we consider answering the question.

If you want to help the OP without keeping the question on the site then you can add a comment, but you do not have to. Remember this is not a help desk and we do not solve all problems thrown at us.

When you write a solution then you have to make sure that it is self-contained. Links to the documentation are not sufficient. They can be used as a reference, but they don't make them the core of your answer.

To make sure that we have easily searchable database of questions, we need you to help us out in keeping this site clean. Vote to delete bad answers and unneeded questions. Flag comments for deletion after they have outlived their usefulness. Edit other posts to remove unnecessary information. If you see spam or offensive content then flag for moderator attention.

**Vote on other questions and answers.** If you think a question is poorly asked and has no value for others than downvote and move on. Don't answer. If you see wrong answer or sloppy (links only, "try this" or low quality in general) then downvote it. If you see something that you think is useful information that should be made more prominent then upvote.

Comment: That wasn't the tag I was thinking of. I do know that the bing-maps tag hasn't been monitored/managed much. I recently looked at it and responded to a handful of questions I knew the answers to without having to dig through any docs.

Comment: @rbrundritt It would actually help to tell which tag you are talking about so others can have a look and be able to assess the situation. I as well assumed it was the bing-maps tag because it was the topic of a [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325945/1288408) asked by you previously.